# Python how to make an exception for non positive numbers

Tags: python, exception, numbers, try-catch, except

How can I raise an exception here to catch nonpositive inputs? Right now nothing gets printed if I input a negative number

```
"""
Generate fibonacci sequence to the nth digit
"""
def fib(n):
    try:
        if n <= 0:
            raise Exception
        prev = 0
        curr = 1
        for terms in range(0, int(n)):
            nxt = prev + curr
            print str(curr),
            prev = curr
            curr = nxt
    except ValueError or Exception:
        new = raw_input("Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer: ")
        fib(new)

n = raw_input("Enter number of terms: ")
fib(n)
```

Comment: You should move the test for negative numbers *outside* the `try` - you *want* it to cause an error! Also note that `try` blocks should be short as possible, and `except` tests as specific as possible, otherwise you hide genuine problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jon says, it's a much better design strategy to separate the input gathering from the core Fibonacci calculation. Also, it's generally better to use a simple loop than to use a recursive call (calling a function inside itself) unless you *really* need recursion (eg, when processing a recursive data structure, like a directory tree).

Here's a modified version of your code. I've made a few other minor changes. In Python, we don't need a temporary variable like `nxt` to do the core Fibonacci calculation. Instead, we use tuple assignment so we can update `curr` and save the old `curr` to `prev` in one step.

```
def input_positive_integer(prompt=''):
    """ Get a positive integer from the user """
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(raw_input(prompt))
            if n <= 0:
                raise ValueError
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "Invalid input.",
            prompt = "Please enter a positive integer: "
    return n

def fib(n):
    """ Print n terms of the Fibonacci sequence """
    prev, curr = 0, 1
    for terms in range(n):
        print curr,
        prev, curr = curr, prev + curr

n = input_positive_integer("Enter number of terms: ")
fib(n)
```

**test**

```
Enter number of terms: -4
Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer: q
Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer: 2.5
Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer: 5
1 1 2 3 5
```

Comment: quick question: when you said 'int(raw_input(prompt))' were you converting the input to an integer? Or were you validating the type of the input

Comment: `raw_input(prompt)` always returns a string. `int(some_string)` attempts to convert `some_string` to an integer, but if `some_string` isn't a valid string representing an integer `int` will raise `ValueError`. So in the expression `int(raw_input(prompt))`, `int` is handling both the conversion and the validation for us. And once we've created the integer `n` we can then go on to verify that `n` is a non-negative integer.

Answer (score 2):

`except ValueError or Exception`

The correct syntax for that is `except (ValueError, Exception)`, but note that since all exceptions inherit from `Exception`, this might misbehave.

You better not raise and try to catch a general exception. 
Instead, raise the already catched `ValueError`:

```
def fib(n):
    try:
        if n <= 0:
            raise ValueError
    .
    .
    .
    except ValueError:
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the core problem here is that your `fib` function has two entirely separate responsibilities:

1. Handling user input and validation; and
2. Calculating Fibonacci numbers.

From the name, I'd say it should only be doing #2!

Instead, structure your program like:

```
def positive_integer():
    """Loops until the user enters a positive integer."""
    ...

def fib(n):
    """Prints first n Fibonacci numbers."""
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError
    prev = 0
    curr = 1
    for terms in range(n):  # note simplification here
        nxt = prev + curr
        print str(curr),
        prev = curr
        curr = nxt

fib(positive_integer())
```

Now you have two functions, each with a clear single responsibility. This makes each one less complex; the `range` call is now simpler, for example, as it can assume `n` is already an integer (and if not, the user gets a sensible `TypeError` to tell them what went wrong).

For writing `positive_input` see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761); a loop is better than recursion for this.

As a further refactor, you can actually cut the three lines

```
nxt = prev + curr
prev = curr
curr = nxt
```

to just one:

```
prev, curr = curr, curr + prev
```

Also note that, in general, you should keep your `try` blocks as short as possible and your `except` clauses as specific as possible. This makes them more useful when reading the code (*"I think this one thing could go wrong, and in that case we can do this about it"*) and means that legitimate problems aren't quietly ignored. In particular, you should almost never be dealing directly with `Exception` (either in `raise` or `except`), it's far too broad a case to handle usefully.

Answer (score 0):

To catch multiple exception types, put them in a tuple. `ValueError or Exception` is a boolean expression that evaluates to ValueError.

Also you should never raise Exception, and you should never ever catch it. Define your own custom exception class.

```
class NonNegativeNumber(Error):
    pass


...
except (ValueError, NonNegativeNumber):
```

However, note that ValueError seems like a perfectly valid exception to raise here; you may not need the more specific class at all.

Comment: `ValueError or Exception` is a boolean expression that evaluates to `ValueError` (as I'm sure you well know).